# How to design Sliding tabs with Android Studio default Navigation drawer?

Tags: android

I want to Implement Navigation drawer with sliding tabs. I have done this by designing my own navigation drawer. Now I want to use Android studio default navigation drawer with sliding tabs. I am not getting any idea???? Can anyone please help me...
THANKS in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been explained here in great detail with code.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Ashish Rawat. I will look at that.

Comment: I have gone through it. I have done that. But I want to select navigation drawer while creating new Activity (New --> Activity --> Navigation Drawer Activity). Now I want to implement Tab layout in this Navigation drawer Activity. Any help would be grateful....

Comment: As you must be using android studio. try File-> New->Import sample, search for navigation drawer, it will create the project with activity and navigation drawer, you can then enhance it for your use.

Answer (score 0):

For New Project:-

Create New Project, while project creating, select Sample Activity like Navigation Drawer Activity Or Tabbed Activity. You can create it by selecting.

Or, In existing Project:-

Goto File --> New --> Activity --> Gallery and Select which you want.

Thanks,